# Cert stored as secret in Azure Key Vault can only have its private keys retrieved once via ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

This is an odd issue.

I created a self-signed certificate and created a PFX file from it.  I then converted the PFX file to a base64-encoded string and stored it as a secret in Azure Key Vault.  I then created a new Windows VM using an ARM Template with the following code:

```
"osProfile": {
  "secrets": [
    {
      "sourceVault": {
        "id": "[parameters('vaultResourceId')]"
      },
      "vaultCertificates": [
        {
          "certificateUrl": "[parameters('headNodeCertPrivateUri')]",
          "certificateStore": "My"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The VM got created, and when I looked in the LocalMachine/My store, I could see the cert sitting pretty with its private keys.  So all is well.

*Every other time* I try to create a VM using this same secret, it imports the certificate without the private keys.  There are no error messages during the deployment.  The ARM Template is identical except for the name of the VM itself.  The cert is where it's supposed to be, in LocalMachine/My, it's just missing its private keys.

I can manually download the cert just fine with its private keys.  The cert itself isn't being changed; there is only version of the secret and the Uri is identically configured in all of the ARM Templates.

The behavior I described above is reproducible.  Create new self-signed cert, upload it to Azure Key Vault, first VM created with ARM Template referencing key has the private keys, all subsequent VM's thus created do not.

This is a head-scratcher for me.  Any idea why this would work the first time but not any subsequent time?

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found the answer.  And it's equally odd.

I didn't tell the full story.  I wasn't just installing the private cert in LocalMachine\My; I was also installing the public cert in LocalMachine\Root.  Because this is a self-signed cert, Windows won't validate a self-signed cert unless there is a matching public cert in LocalMachine\Root.

My complete "secrets" section in ARM was:

```
"vaultCertificates": [
    {
        "certificateUrl": "[parameters('headNodeCertPrivateUri')]",
        "certificateStore": "My"
    },
    {
        "certificateUrl": "[parameters('headNodeCertPublicUri')]",
        "certificateStore": "Root"
    }
```

I think what happened is this:  It installs the private cert and Windows won't accept the private keys because it can't find a trusted root cert, and *then* it install the public cert.

I simply flipped it around to this:

```
"vaultCertificates": [
    {
        "certificateUrl": "[parameters('headNodeCertPublicUri')]",
        "certificateStore": "Root"
    },
    {
        "certificateUrl": "[parameters('headNodeCertPrivateUri')]",
        "certificateStore": "My"
    }
```

And then the private cert was installed just fine.

So why did it work the first time when it was in the wrong order?  I can only guess that because the private cert is much longer than the public cert, it takes more time to retrieve from the key vault, so Azure orders the public cert first above the private cert.  Thereafter the certs are cached in the Azure backend somewhere, and future ARM deployments will install them in the order you specify.

The above is pure speculation.

**What this all proves is that I cannot trust in which order the certs are going to be installed via an ARM Template.**  So I'm going to have to do a multi-step deployment.  I'll first create the VM with just the public cert, then do another deployment for just the private cert.

I tested this and it works:  The public cert gets installed via the ARM Template for the VM, then the private cert gets installed correctly when the second ARM Template containing only the private cert is deployed.

Feature request:  Allow us to specify in which order secrets are installed.  :)